# Is it possible to save http-hosted MP3 files directly onto an iPad?

Tags: ipad, safari, mp3

Is there a way to save an MP3 from a web server directly onto an iPad?  I can stream it through the browser, but there is no obvious "save" capability.

Would it make a difference if the MP3 were an email attachment?

Comment: Similar: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/how-to-download-an-mp3-to-an-ipod-touch

Comment: I don't know why this question is protected but you can use Downcast podcast app which has an import via URL under Tools

Comment: I had the same problem. I sent some mp3 files to my e-mail account and I downloaded it stating to save to iMovie. After that launching iMovie -> Audio -> Imported the file appeared.

Comment: The fact that I am "not allowed" to use my device to use my media as I wish is ludicrous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As fas as I know there is no way to save an MP3 file directly from the web. What you can do is jailbreak your iPad and then try saving it.

Comment: Downloading mp3 via a URL now seems to be supported natively by Safari on iOS 14. Chrome - not so much.

Answer (score 10):

My favorite is [Documents by Readdle](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8). It has a builtin browser.

You can simply browse your desired webpage and download different kinds of files like mp3, pdf and others into your iPad directly and enjoy playing or reading them in the same application.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough, this was super simple and EXACTLY what I needed.  I needed to download word pronunciations from Forvo, and this was the only way that worked so far, built in browser is easy to use.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a roundabout way of doing it.

1. Create a [Drobox](http://db.tt/gmROYTQ) account and install the Drobox app on your Mac and
   iPhone.
2. Use http://urldroplet.com/ to save the mp3 to your Drobox account.
3. Open Drobox on your iPhone, you can star it so it's downloaded and kept for offline access.

Comment: -1. Amazing idea, unfortunately gives a 500 error all the time :-(

Answer (score 5):

You could save it into an app, such as [AirSharing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing/id289943355?mt=8), then use iTunes to save the file to your computer, then put it into the Music Library like normal.

There is unfortunately no direct way to get a file contained somewhere on the Web, or even in an app, into the music library/video library, without first using iTunes.

Same goes for having it e-mailed to you. You can always access the e-mail and re-stream the MP3, but note the emphasis on that. *Continually Stream the MP3*.

You must use iTunes to get it into your library without any other significant process, such as Jailbreak as noted by Chirag.

Answer (score 5):

[GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) is what you're looking for. Copy the URL into it or use the built in browser to find the file you want then download it.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, by jailbreaking the iPad and then installing a tweak called Safari Download Manager. This will allow you to save any file from Safari to your iPad.